# Javascript not loading in Safari

Tags: javascript, wordpress, safari

Im working on a site that I'm launching tonight and for the life of me cannot figure out why my scripts are not working in Safari. All is fine in Chrome but it seems like the scripts arent even loading for the site in safari. Im loading the scrips using wordpress's wp_enqueue_script() function and this is how the scripts are rendering in the source

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/scrolling-nav.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/responsiveScript.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/signup-script.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/slide-script.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://52.26.145.136/FitnessFifteen/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fitnessfifteen/js/clients-script.js?ver=4.5.3'></script>
```

Comment: No error messages on web end. Is there any way I can tell if there is error messages on mobile? @UnknownDeveloper

Comment: Seems that safari identifies locally deployed files as insecure content. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883306/safari-9-disallowed-running-of-insecure-content

Comment: there is this error: ar $ = jQuery.noConflict(); in scrolling-nav.js. Change ar.. to var...

Comment: @gaetanoM fixed that error. Still having the issue

Comment: @LukeP.Issac Im not sure how to go about implementing a solution for the question you posted. That seems above my head. Im running the site on an amazon ec2 instance