# Im trying to link an external custom javascript file to my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to link a basic javascript file from one web server to another the same way that cloud-based jquery files work. However, when I link it like their files as seen below the alert stored in the external file doesn't trigger. I know this isn't the best practice to do this, however, for the small task it is required. Any suggestions would be great.

**Link**

```
<script src="http://example.com/javascriptfile.js"></script>
```

**JS File**

```
(function() {
  alert("Matt it worked bud");
})
```

Comment: You need to execute the function as well, not just declare it as an unused expression. Add `()` to the end

Comment: @CertainPerformance The alert still isn't being executed and when I click on the script src in the editor unlike the other files, mine opens and new tab not the code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the link so that the `src` points to the actual file

Comment: @CertainPerformance the link to the file is <script src="http://matthammond.co.uk/tot/EmailScript.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute it. Like this:

```
(function() {
  alert("Matt it worked bud");
})();
```

Reading this may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/IIFE

As we have discussed in the chat, this question is relevant to your problem: [Safari 9 disallowed running of insecure content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883306/safari-9-disallowed-running-of-insecure-content)

Comment: The alert still isn't being executed and when I click on the script src in the editor unlike the other files, mine opens and new tab not the code.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by "when I click on the script src in the editor unlike the other files, mine opens and new tab not the code". Can you reformulate please ?

Comment: Not to sure how to explain it but basiclly the url is being taken as a webpage but not a file

Comment: I meant inspect element, sorry! And Safari

Comment: That's because it's a url and it's not in your own filesystem. But when it opens in the other tab, can you see the javascript code ? If you can't that means you're using the wrong url. I mean that the file for js isn't in the location you think it is, or there's some feature of http server disallowing the access to the file.

Comment: The link is  <script src="matthammond.co.uk/tot/EmailScript.js"></script> and if you click it, it goes to the js code. But never get executed by more another website. However with other external files work for example, <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Is it something to do something with my server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176188/discussion-between-nelson-teixeira-and-matt-hammond).

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't be triggered because you haven't called it.

```
<script>
 (function() {
  alert("Matt it worked bud");
 })();
</script>
```

You may also want to look into Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).