# Safari Only: Codesandbox unable to get data from localhost server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, axios, codesandbox

Server / API: https://github.com/LambdaSchool/trinkets-api

Mock website: https://codesandbox.io/s/pt14-httpajax-ii-0176m?file=/src/components/Item.js

In the code it uses axios to request data from the server running locally on my machine. It works in Google Chrome but not Safari ... why and how do I solve this?

Safari Version 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8)

Comment: Does the Safari network panel or the console panel show any errors? Does the same happen on Firefox or any other browser?

Comment: [blocked] The page at https://codesandbox.io/s/pt14-httpajax-ii-0176m?file=/src/components/UpdateForm.js was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:3333/items.

Not allowed to request resource

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3333/items due to access control checks.

Comment: It works fine in Google Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I'm assuming it's because it's over http and not https. Was hoping there was a work around or an allow mixed content setting but I haven't been able to find one in recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Try enabling https for your local server. Safari does not allow mixed content. See [Safari 9 disallowed running of insecure content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883306/safari-9-disallowed-running-of-insecure-content)