# Modify JavaScript src url in client side browser

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

Safari has a limitation where if the page url is https, http resources cannot be used inside the page ([mixed content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879321)).

I do not control any of the websites, so I cannot change the script src server side, however, my iOS app allows users to browse pages that contain a script that is being loaded from localhost, so it's insecure:

```
<script language="javascript">var localhostExists=false;</script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:1234/script.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   if(localhostExists){
      document.write("Server is working");
   }else{
      document.write("Server is not working");
   }
</script>
```

`http://127.0.0.1:1234/script.js` simply returns `localhostExists=true;` to say that it's present.

Safari blocks this, so I am trying to find a workaround. This works fine on Android with Chrome.

Is it possible to inject some JS before the page loads that will change any occurrence of `http://127.0.0.1:1234/script.js` to another url before the page is rendered, a url I can host myself that's secure e.g. `https://my-endpoint/script.js`?

If it's not possible to do it before, could the script source be changed after the initial render and re-executed?

Comment: So you can't execute your scripts,  but you want to inject a script that will then allow you to execute your scripts?

Comment: @Kaiido it is a strange this to need to do. the problem is, Safari is blocking this one script from running automatically to let the website know localhost is available. 127.0.0.1 is available and works fine on iOS, the website can access it at the push of buttons etc.., just not execute JS automatically from it. The website will hide said buttons, because this script that checks if localhost is available is blocked.

Comment: Ok, but if you're unable to execute scripts, how do you want to execute scripts that will unlock your script? And if you can execute scripts, why don't you execute whatever is in that script from where you can execute scripts?

Comment: @Kaiido it's not that I can't execute scripts, just scripts located on insecure hosts. your second comment was what I needed to hear. I could simply insert a script before the page loads with 'let localhostExists=true;', the webpage uses this global property instead of the local one to determine if localhost is available